# How to delete default padding Top and Bottom in ExpansionTile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to delete default padding Top and Bottom in ExpansionTile ?

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: ListTileTheme(
    dense: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: ExpansionTile(
      backgroundColor: widget.backgroundColor ?? MyColors.white,
      onExpansionChanged: widget.onExpansionChanged,
      initiallyExpanded: widget.initialExpanded ?? false,
      iconColor: MyColors.black5,
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 12.0),
      childrenPadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, right: 12.0),
      title: Text(
        widget.title,
        style: widget.textStyle ??
            MyThemeData.textTheme.caption
                ?.copyWith(color: MyColors.black5, height: 1),
      ),
      children: widget.child,
    ),
  ),
);
```

i've try remove default padding use ListTileTheme. work for horizontal padding but not Vertical padding

so, how to remove vertical padding ?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
ListTileTheme(
       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
       child: ExpansionTile(...)
    )
```

Comment: just change left and right padding.. but, top and bottom not change

Comment: add this in ListTileTheme..  dense: true

Answer (score 0):

Use `SizedBox` as child:

```
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
//         body: Center(
        body: NewGame(),
//         ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewGameState createState() => _NewGameState();
}

class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  int? numberOfPlayers = 4;
  var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Game"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
            child: ListTileTheme(
                dense: true,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  initiallyExpanded: true,
                  iconColor: Colors.black,
                  title: Text('TITLE'),
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow[900],
                            ),
                            child: Text("""Some long text: 
                                kwdjkwed wekdjkwedmkwemd wkqmdk
                        //       wqmdkqwmdkqwmd \
                        //       wqmdkqwmdkqwmd \
                        //       wqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmdwqmdkqwmdkqwmd kwqmdkqwmd kqwmdkqwmdkqwmdqwk dkqwmdkqw md
                        //       333 444 55 666 777 888 """)
                            // ),
                            ))
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i need set top and bottom title padding not in children